# Eclipse marketplace - cannot install asciidoc editor

Tags: eclipse, maven, marketplace

I am trying to install the asciidoc editor plugin from the marketplace. However it shows an error as it is missing some dependency

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Asciidoctor Editor 2.1.1 (de.jcup.asciidoctoreditor.feature.group 2.1.1)
  Missing requirement: Asciidoctor Editor 2.1.1 (de.jcup.asciidoctoreditor 2.1.1) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.search 3.11.400' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Asciidoctor Editor 2.1.1 (de.jcup.asciidoctoreditor.feature.group 2.1.1)
    To: de.jcup.asciidoctoreditor [2.1.1]
```

Could you anyone help with how to resolve this.

Eclipse: Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)

The Asciidoc editor website shows that it supports  Neon (4.6). Please do let me know how to solve this.
I tried adding the dependency to the pom from https://frontbackend.com/maven/artifact/org.eclipse.platform/org.eclipse.search/3.11.400, but it dint help

Thank you!

Comment: org.eclipse.search version 3.11.400 is in Eclipse 2018-12 so nothing earlier will work with that install. maven has nothing to do with installing plug-ins in Eclipse.

Comment: oh. is it. Thanks! Could you please tell me where you saw this, so that it can help in future error resolutions

Comment: I didn't see it anywhere online. I have all the Eclipse releases downloaded and looked at the installed plug-in versions.

Comment: Try with Eclipse 2018-12 instead.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen The first comment already said Eclipse 2018-12 or higher is required. Please do not recommend to use outdated versions. Eclipse 2018-12 is 5 releases behind and there is a separate Stack Exchange for [retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @howlger I know.  Question was if the plugin worked with that particular release or not as it contains the stated dependency.  OP might be happy to be on an older version if it does until the maintainers get around to test it with the latest.    Also I suggest you actually spend some time on the retrocomputing site before suggesting again anything is more appropriate there.  This is much too new for them.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Why do you think that it does not work with the current Eclipse version, in contrast to the documentation and the Marketplace data? You should know better than to recommend software that has been outdated for so long.

Comment: @howlger I have no idea - therefore the wording "try" which at least _could_ potentially help.  If the plugin works for you, or can be made to work for you, then please write the procedure up in an answer.